# Lego Jurassic World achievement will not pop

Tags: achievements, xbox-one, lego-jurassic-world

I have completed Lego Jurassic World and have 100% completion.  But.  One of the achievements will not pop.

[image: Lego Jurassic World 100% Completion]

This one to be precise:

[image: Are you following the dinosaur?]

I've played through that specific one several times (to collect all the 'stuff') so I have definitely completed it.

Is there some magic trick to getting the achievement to fire in these cases?  Start a new game save?  Uninstall/reinstall?  Pray to the Lego gods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Xbox achievements forum](https://www.xboxachievements.com/forum/topic/418814-achievement-guide-and-roadmap/#comment-6104377):

> It has been reported that some of the level completion achievements are not unlocking in Story Mode. This could be due to the app not working properly or it could be connected to the checkpoint save stations. In past LEGO games, if you use this mid-level save station and “Save & Exit”, when you return to complete the level, you will find that the achievement doesn't unlock. The only known fix to this is to restart the level from the beginning and play all the way through in one sitting.

Since it's a story-related achievement, I fear you may have to start a new save and play the story again.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that and see if that fixes the issue.  Not like playing the game is some tedious torture.  :-)

Comment: Confirmed.  Replaying the episode with a brand new save enables the achievement to pop.

Comment: @ReginaldBlue good to know!